# quasar failed on RUN quasar build

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I want to build quasar project with command quasar build. The compile progress goes to 100% but I get the error after build:

```
App · ⚠️  1 error encountered:

./node_modules/htmlparser2/lib/esm/index.js 59:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (59:9)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@quasar/app/lib/webpack/loader.transform-quasar-imports.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|     return getFeed(parseDOM(feed, options));
| }
> export * as DomUtils from "domutils";
| // Old name for DomHandler
| export { DomHandler as DefaultHandler };
 @ ./node_modules/sanitize-html/index.js 1:19-41
 @ ./node_modules/vue-sanitize/dist/vue-sanitize.js
 @ ./src/boot/sanitize.ts
 @ ./.quasar/client-entry.js
 @ multi ./.quasar/client-entry.js

 App · ⚠️  [FAIL] Build failed with 1 error. Check log above.
```

This is my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "rfasdef",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "productName": "",
  "cordovaId": "",
  "capacitorId": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore ./"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^3.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "echarts": "^4.6.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "jalaali-js": "^1.2.3",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.3.2",
    "moment-jalaali": "^0.9.6",
    "num2persian": "^3.2.2",
    "persianjs": "^0.4.0",
    "qjdatetime": "^1.1.0",
    "quasar": "^1.9.5",
    "sass": "^1.45.0",
    "vue-echarts": "^5.0.0-beta.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-persian-datetime-picker": "^2.10.1",
    "vue-sanitize": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@quasar/app": "^1.6.2",
    "@quasar/quasar-app-extension-dotenv": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.150",
    "@types/moment-jalaali": "^0.7.5",
    "@types/node": "^10.17.15",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.17.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.17.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.1.2",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.3.0",
    "vuex-class": "^0.3.2",
    "vuex-module-decorators": "^0.11.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 10.18.1",
    "npm": ">= 6.13.4",
    "yarn": ">= 1.21.1"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 1 version, not dead, ie >= 11"
  ],
  "resolutions": {
    "@babel/parser": "7.7.5"
  }
}
```

It was working yesterday but today it's not working!
I tried installing packages with both yarn and npm. But its not working.

Comment: Have you tried this with a fresh quasar project just for checking if it works? It seems these kinds of errors point to version differences. Maybe you should update the packages or npm/yarn.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Deleting package-lock.json and folder node_modules
2. then run npm install or yarn install
3. then run quasar build

Answer (score 0):

Search for new ecma script syntax in your code, for example .? | ??

**updated:**

Sorry for the late reply.

the error can be due to the node version or lack of installation of ecma script related packages

An important point in the error: "**You may need an additional loader to handle the result**"

## method1:

1. Update node version at least ^16 or ^18

If not possible for you, consider the second method.

## method2:

1. update babel.config.js as follows

```
module.exports = {
  'presets': ['@quasar/babel-preset-app'],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
}
```

2. install following packages:

```
npm i -D @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
```

or

```
yarn add -D @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34665413)